# Can't ping Internet IPs from Docker Container

Tags: networking, centos, docker, ping

I am unable to ping any public IP from docker Container (CentOS) it's not about hostname or any DNS but IP, can ping to the docker0 network IP 172.17.0.1 but not to the internet IP

```
[root@09ae7f091d98 /]# ping 172.17.0.1
    PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
    64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
    ^C
    --- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.059/0.067/0.076/0.011 ms
```

Gateway is properly configured

```
[root@09ae7f091d98 /]# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2
```

Container IP is properly configured

```
[root@09ae7f091d98 /]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: eth0@if7: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

DNS

```
[root@09ae7f091d98 /]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.20.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Host is also having correct IPs & Gateway

```
[root@centos7-client ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:fb:4c:9e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.0.23/16 brd 10.20.255.255 scope global noprefixroute ens33
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f15d:3d1c:5ff5:4473/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:50:e9:22:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:50ff:fee9:2283/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: veth1183670@if6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker0 state UP group default
    link/ether 0e:86:53:9c:c1:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::c86:53ff:fe9c:c1ef/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[root@centos7-client ~]# ip route
default via 10.20.0.1 dev ens33 proto static metric 100
10.20.0.0/16 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.0.23 metric 100
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
```

I have also temporarily disabled SELinux and Firewalld but still unable to figure out what's wrong

```
[root@centos7-client ~]# getenforce
Permissive
[root@centos7-client ~]# systemctl status firewalld.service
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2022-03-02 11:29:54 PKT; 10min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
  Process: 744 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid $FIREWALLD_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 744 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/targ... that name.
Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1' failed: iptables: No chain/targ... that name.
Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed: iptables: No chain/targ... that name.
Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2' failed: iptables: No chain/targ... that name.
Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -F DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Mar 02 09:49:08 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -t filter -X DOCKER-ISOLATION' failed: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
Mar 02 09:49:09 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (...at chain?).
Mar 02 09:49:10 centos7-client firewalld[744]: WARNING: COMMAND_FAILED: '/usr/sbin/iptables -w10 -D FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j DROP' failed: iptables: Bad rule (...at chain?).
Mar 02 11:29:53 centos7-client systemd[1]: Stopping firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
Mar 02 11:29:54 centos7-client systemd[1]: Stopped firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

note that docker service is running fine but when i use dockerd it shows following error, also tried to reinstall docker-ce but still shows the same

```
[root@centos7-client ~]# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-03-02 11:32:07 PKT; 10min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 2530 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 10
   Memory: 38.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─2530 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.531081666+05:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/contai...module=grpc
Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.531098252+05:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.543719460+05:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"
Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.559064109+05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.890565609+05:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17...IP address"
Mar 02 11:32:06 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:06.984869372+05:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 02 11:32:07 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:07.024522345+05:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=459d0df graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=20.10.12
Mar 02 11:32:07 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:07.024716059+05:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 02 11:32:07 centos7-client systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 02 11:32:07 centos7-client dockerd[2530]: time="2022-03-02T11:32:07.054705588+05:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
[root@centos7-client ~]# dockerd
INFO[2022-03-02T11:42:16.512435705+05:00] Starting up
failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid
```

using CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) on host machine (it's a vm in which i am using docker and in vmware setting the network adapter is set to bridge mode) host can ping public IPs

```
[root@centos7-client ~]# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=1 time=7.19 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=1 time=5.94 ms
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.945/6.571/7.198/0.631 ms
```

but container can't

```
[root@centos7-client ~]# docker attach sad_ellis
[root@09ae7f091d98 /]# ping 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4000ms
```

can anyone please guide me how to resolve this issue, I can't figure it out what's wrong with the config

thank you

EDIT:

```
[root@centos7-workstation ~]# iptables -S -t nat
-P PREROUTING ACCEPT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-P POSTROUTING ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N OUTPUT_direct
-N POSTROUTING_ZONES
-N POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-N POSTROUTING_direct
-N POST_docker
-N POST_docker_allow
-N POST_docker_deny
-N POST_docker_log
-N POST_public
-N POST_public_allow
-N POST_public_deny
-N POST_public_log
-N PREROUTING_ZONES
-N PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-N PREROUTING_direct
-N PRE_docker
-N PRE_docker_allow
-N PRE_docker_deny
-N PRE_docker_log
-N PRE_public
-N PRE_public_allow
-N PRE_public_deny
-N PRE_public_log
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_direct
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A PREROUTING -j PREROUTING_ZONES
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_direct
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES_SOURCE
-A POSTROUTING -j POSTROUTING_ZONES
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o docker0 -g POST_docker
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -o ens33 -g POST_public
-A POSTROUTING_ZONES -g POST_public
-A POST_docker -j POST_docker_log
-A POST_docker -j POST_docker_deny
-A POST_docker -j POST_docker_allow
-A POST_public -j POST_public_log
-A POST_public -j POST_public_deny
-A POST_public -j POST_public_allow
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i docker0 -g PRE_docker
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -i ens33 -g PRE_public
-A PREROUTING_ZONES -g PRE_public
-A PRE_docker -j PRE_docker_log
-A PRE_docker -j PRE_docker_deny
-A PRE_docker -j PRE_docker_allow
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_log
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_deny
-A PRE_public -j PRE_public_allow


[root@centos7-workstation ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: Please add output of `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and `iptables -S -t nat` of the host

Comment: @Virsacer please check I have edited the question section

Comment: Way more rules than I expected, but the nessessary ones are there... Did you manually edit iptables? Perhaps stopping docker daemon, removing all rules/chains and starting docker again helps...